# MVC Checkbox Formatting Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to find a way to display the checkbox and some text to the right properly.  The default way the MVC View lays them out puts the checkbox below the label / text.  So I tried to get them on the same line with this simplified code, but the text still rides up about half a line above the checkbox.  How can you display a checkbox and some text to the right of the checkbox on the same line with proper vertical alignment for the text on the right?  Thank you!

```
<div>                    
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DriverDBARequired) &nbsp; Driver DBA Required                     
</div>
```

Comment: It can be dependent on your editor template and styling, but try using `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DriverDBARequired, "Driver DBA Required")` for the label.

Comment: the editor (checkbox) and lablefor (the text) need to appear on the same line.  using separate @Html.EditorFor and LableFor's put them on separate lines.

Comment: Okay, well that is dependent on your css. Try enclosing the 'EditorFor` in a `label` tag.

Comment: do you mean like this: <div><label>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DriverDBARequired) &nbsp; Driver DBA Required</label></div>

Answer (score 0):

This must be a CSS issue. The standard site.css might cause that behavior:

```
label {
  **display: block;**
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

If you change it to

```
display: inline
```

it should work. The following lines in the standard site.css can help you too:

```
label.checkbox {
  display: inline;
}
```

Write your checkbox like something as:

```
<label class="checkbox">@Html.CheckBox("MyName", false) My text</label>
```